# ¿Como corregir el error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 al cargar un archivo en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, xml

El problema que me surgió es que antes tenia el código de esta forma

```
        $rules = [
            'factura_pdf.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf',
            'factura_xml.*' => 'required|mimes:xml'
        ];

        $mssages = [
            'factura_pdf.required' => 'Debe de seleccionar la factura en formato pdf.',
            'factura_xml.required' => 'Debe de seleccionar la factura en formato xml.',
            'factura_pdf.mimes' => 'El archivo debe ser de tipo pdf.',
            'factura_xml.mimes' => 'El archivo debe ser de tipo xml.'
        ];
```

Y había estado funcionando bien en mi pagina de producción pero ahora ya no funciona y me captura el error de que el archivo xml no es correcto, pero el archivo tiene la estructura que se había estado utilizando hasta ahora

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
message: "The given data was invalid."
errors: {factura_xml.0: ["El campo factura_xml.0 debe ser un archivo de tipo xml."]}
factura_xml.0: ["El campo factura_xml.0 debe ser un archivo de tipo xml."]
0: "El campo factura_xml.0 debe ser un archivo de tipo xml."
```

Ese es el error que me marca cuando envió el formulario con el archivo pdf y xml, el 0 que muestra es porque le permito al usuario subir múltiples archivos, estuve revisando la documentación de laravel pero no encuentro nada diferente a lo que yo uso

Comment: Podrias colocar todo el codigo ya que este no es ejemplo minimo verificable!

Comment: Que parte del código ? la parte de la función crear donde tengo la validación ??